# Get Component/entity model from component tcm

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-net

We have articles that are published on pages.
For one article we want to call the Entity from the broker database (on cd server).
It is not DCP? I dn't know.

Code from MVC Controller (it's a REST API thats called from frontend).

```
            var localization = new Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization()
            {
                Language = "Nederlands",
                Id = "102",   // publication id of the website
            };

            var provider = new Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.GraphQLContentProvider();

            // Use the Component tcm - component template tcm
            EntityModel entityModel = provider.GetEntityModel("418926-418875", localization);
```

this results in Exception:

{"Item '418926-418875' not found"}
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.LoadEntityModel(String id, Localization localization)\r\n
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__0()\r\n
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.CreateCacheValue[T](UInt32 hash, String key, String region, Func`1 addFunction, IEnumerable`1 dependencies)\r\n
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func`1 addFunction, IEnumerable`1 dependencies)\r\n
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetEntityModel(String id, Localization localization)\r\n
at Uwv.eDv.Web.Modules.Core.Controllers.CustomOverzichtApiController.Post(OverzichtInput input)
in D:\..\Controllers\CustomOverzichtApiController.cs:line 60"

**Questions.**

1. Is this DCP? If not how can be get it's information without being DCP.
2. Is there other way to get Entitymodel from broker database. Sample?

**Update-1:**
Changed CT to DCP, but still not works.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To access the DCP components from the broker using the Graphql DXA entity model - components should be published to the broker.

At least from sites 9.5, it's possible by data template less publishing to get that data from broker using Graphql.

I don't see any other option to fetch this information without publishing it as DCP.

Comment: I made new DCP for this component, and used that on the page. The CT only chage i made in it is changed to "Component Presentations based on this Component Template will be:" Publish as a Dynamic Component". tested both check/uncheck for "Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly". When excute "provider.GetEntityModel .." with this it thorws Exception: {"PCA client returned an unexpected response when retrieving enity model data for id 418926-419027."} Is more needed?

Comment: With DCP Exception: {"PCA client returned an unexpected response when retrieving entity model data for id 418926-419027."}  
Exception while fetching data (/componentPresentation/rawContent) : Error occurred while transforming component presentation content at Line : 5 Column :4\r\n"}  Why?

Comment: Maybe site 9 has also this. https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000013754